# What is the best practice to apply a note inside a data table?

Tags: data-tables

Example Scenario: 
As a user I need to update multiple data columns in a single row in  but notes are necessary so that other users will know the reason.

So what do you think is the best practice?

My thoughts are:
1. A button(modal to add noted, 
2. An action column with item saying "add notes", or (your idea).

Let me know if you have any questions

Thanks,
Edwin

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here you have example table. After click **more** (I interaction) and **edit** (II interaction) Every **cell** from selected **row** changing to edit possible - while the 3 dots (III - edit mode) changing to button **approving** **edition**.

In this moment the information about note can show in the same manner as before (I-II Interaction):

[image]

---

Adding note can display in **tooltip** at the end of the line.